# Скрыть/показать div кнопкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Скорее всего, это будет очередным тупым вопросом, но, с высоты **моих** познаний в скриптах, это довольно серьезно. Так вот..

Есть форма поиска, которая выводит результат в подготовленный для нее `.s-results`, при этом остальной контент страницы (`.site-main`) остается висеть после результатов поиска.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "поиск" основной контент (`.site-main`) скрывался, при этом нужно показать кнопку ("Скрыть результаты поиска"), которая совершит обратное действие (показать `site-main` и очистить `s-results`)? В идеале этой же кнопкой еще очистить бы форму..

Код формы:

```
<form id="ajax_wpqsffrom_91">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="4fbdf7ac27">
  <input type="hidden" name="aformid" value="91">
  <input type="hidden" id="jaxbtn" value="#content">
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-0">
    <label class="tax-label-0">Район</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[0][name]" value="area">
    <select id="taxselect-0" name="taxo[0][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Все районы</option>
      <option value="area1">Район1</option>
      <option value="area2">Район2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-1">
    <label class="tax-label-1">Застройщик</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[1][name]" value="developers">
    <select id="taxselect-1" name="taxo[1][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Все застройщики</option>
      <option value="dev1">Застройщик1</option>
      <option value="dev2">Застройщик2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-2">
    <label class="tax-label-2">Срок сдачи</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[2][name]" value="dline">
    <select id="taxselect-2" name="taxo[2][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Любой</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-3">
    <label class="tax-label-3">Количество комнат</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[3][name]" value="rooms">
    <select id="taxselect-3" name="taxo[3][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Любое</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="4more">4+</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-4">
    <label class="tax-label-4">Цена</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[4][name]" value="price">
    <select id="taxselect-4" name="taxo[4][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Любая</option>
      <option value="0-1mil">0-1 млн.руб.</option>
      <option value="1-2mill">1-2 млн.руб</option>
      <option value="2-3mill">2-3 млн.руб</option>
      <option value="3-4mill">3-4 млн.руб</option>
      <option value="4moremill">4+ млн.руб</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class taxdropdown-5">
    <label class="tax-label-5">Рубрика</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="taxo[5][name]" value="heading">
    <select id="taxselect-5" name="taxo[5][term]">
      <option selected="" value="awpqsftaxoall">Любая</option>
      <option value="sells">Акции</option>
      <option value="near_subway">Квартиры у метро</option>
      <option value="low">Малоэтажное строительство</option>
      <option value="prem">Премиум объекты</option>
      <option value="start">Старты продаж</option>
      <option value="hits">Хиты продаж</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="awpqsf_class awpqsf_submit">
    <input type="button" id="awpqsf_id_btn" value="Поиск" alt="[Submit]" class="searchbtn">
  </div>
</form>
```

Скрипт формы:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('body').on('click','.searchbtn', function(e) {
            passing_data($(this));
            return false;
        });

        $('body').on('click','.pagievent', function(e) {
            var pagenumber =  $(this).attr('id');
            var formid = $('#curform').val();
            pagination_ajax(pagenumber, formid);
            return false;
        });

        $('body').on('keypress','.awpqsftext',function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            passing_data($(this));
          }
        });

        window.passing_data = function ($obj) {

            var ajxdiv = $obj.closest("form").find("#jaxbtn").val();    
            var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'mloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};

            var getdata = $obj.closest("form").serialize();
            var pagenum = '1';

            jQuery.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',   
                 url: ajax.url,
                 data: ({action : 'awpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
                 beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty();res.container.append(res.loader);},
                 success: function(html) {
                    res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
                  $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);


                 }
                 });

        }   

        window.pagination_ajax = function (pagenum, formid) {
            var ajxdiv = $(''+formid+'').find("#jaxbtn").val(); 
            var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'mloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};
            var getdata = $(''+formid+'').serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',   
                 url: ajax.url,
                 data: ({action : 'awpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
                 beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty(); res.container.append(res.loader);},
                 success: function(html) {
                  res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
                  $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);

                //res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
                 }
                 });
        }

     $('body').on('click', '.awpsfcheckall',function () {

        $(this).closest('.togglecheck').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

         });
});//end of script
```

Comment: добавьте код пожалуйста)

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="clearDiv()">
function clearDiv() {
             document.getElementById("form").text="";
} Вот пример для очистки

Comment: @niklex, спасибо за ответ, как понять этот код? что он делает?

Comment: я понял только, что при клике очищает див(в скобки вставить его имя), а дальше?

Comment: этот код просто очищает див с id "form"

Comment: @niklex, хорошо, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Обидно. Но в любом случае, ответ должен быть ответом.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sButton = document.querySelector('.s-button'),
  resultCont = document.querySelector('.s-result'),
  mainCont = document.querySelector('.main-site'),
  n = 0,
  showResult = function(e){

    e.target.value == 'search' ? e.target.value = 'clear' : e.target.value = 'search';
    resultCont.innerHTML == '' ? resultCont.innerHTML = 'results #' + n++ : resultCont.innerHTML = '';
    mainCont.classList.toggle('hidden');
  };

sButton.addEventListener('click', showResult, false);
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="s-button" value="search">
<div class="s-result"></div>
<div class="main-site">main content</div>
```

Comment: Господи Иисусе, оно работает

Comment: А на странице - нет :( если я правильно понял, достаточно обернуть код в script, для проверки.

при нажатии на поиск value меняется на search, в консоль записывается ошибка

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of nullshowResult @ (index):260`
контент не скрывается, при последующих нажатиях ничего не происходит, кроме изменения value кнопки и записи этой ошибки в консоли, только скрипт поиска исправно выдает результаты

Comment: Классы надо в соответствие привести. Контейнер для результатов - класс "s-result", для данных сайта - класс "main-site". Вообще если с js малознаком, то конечно этого примера будет не достаточно

Comment: К счастью, немного знаком, просто забыл в css добавить строку. Но все равно, здесь налицо конфликт - скрипт поиска при каждом нажатии на кнопку выводит результаты, соответственно clear не работает, работа стопорится и бесконечно висит loading. Можно ли записать clear в отдельную кнопку, а эту не трогать?

Comment: покажи свой код, пжлста

Comment: какой именно код?

Comment: который не работает О_о

Comment: `<script>
    var sButton = document.querySelector('.searchbtn'),
  resultCont = document.querySelector('.results'),
  mainCont = document.querySelector('.wrap-content'),
  n = 0,
  showResult = function(e){

    e.target.value == 'search' ? e.target.value = 'clear' : e.target.value = 'search';
    resultCont.innerHTML == '' ? resultCont.innerHTML = 'results #' + n++ : resultCont.innerHTML = '';
    mainCont.classList.toggle('hidden');
  };

sButton.addEventListener('click', showResult, false);
  </script>`

да он работает, просто пусть работает чуть по-другому

Comment: можно весь код? разметку, стили, скрипт

Comment: закинул в вопрос

Comment: Конечно можно сделать отдельную кнопку на очистку. С jquery не работаю, к сожалению

Comment: все равно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="clearDiv()"> //html
function clearDiv() { document.getElementById("form").text=""; } //javascript
```

При нажатии на кнопку, `div` с id `form` будет очищаться)